# How can I make 2 horizontally scrolling divs move independently?

Tags: jquery, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have multiple horizontally scrolling divs on a page I'm building.  I'd like them to move independently of one another (when one scrolls the others stay put) but right now they all move together.

Here's a jsfiddle of the basic code that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2HxCH/2/

And here's the javascript that runs both scrollers:

```
(function () {

    var scrollHandle = 0,
        scrollStep = 5,
        parent = $("#container, #container2");

    //Start the scrolling process
    $(".panner").on("mouseenter", function () {
        var data = $(this).data('scrollModifier'),
            direction = parseInt(data, 10);

        $(this).addClass('active');

        startScrolling(direction, scrollStep);
    });

    //Kill the scrolling
    $(".panner").on("mouseleave", function () {
        stopScrolling();
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    //Actual handling of the scrolling
    function startScrolling(modifier, step) {
        if (scrollHandle === 0) {
            scrollHandle = setInterval(function () {
                var newOffset = parent.scrollLeft() + (scrollStep * modifier);

                parent.scrollLeft(newOffset);
            }, 10);
        }
    }

    function stopScrolling() {
        clearInterval(scrollHandle);
        scrollHandle = 0;
    }

}());
```

I've tried everything I could think of within the CSS and html to separate them, so I'm guessing the fix is in the js.  Any ideas or suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're sharing `scrollHandle` and your other variables between the two `div`s.  You might use the [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) method to keep the state of each independently.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/2HxCH/8/) an update of your fiddle that I think is working how you want. The problem was you were setting the parent to be both of the divs. I added a way to differentiate between which div should be scrolled.

Here's the relevant change:

```
//Start the scrolling process
$(".panner").on("mouseenter", function () {
    var data = $(this).data('scrollModifier'),
        direction = parseInt(data, 10);
    var parentId = $(this).data('scrollDiv');
    parent = $('#' + parentId);

    $(this).addClass('active');

    startScrolling(direction, scrollStep);
});
```